# Doctrine 2 Postgresql stored procedure mapping

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I'd like to associate to a doctrine entity a postgresql stored procedure (which returns a table as result) instead of a table.

Ex: the procedure Get_Uuser(sexe, age) search all the users for the selected parameters and returns a collection of user_id (names user_id_rech for example).

In pgsql, I can use this stored procedure as a table :

```
select user_name 
from User 
left join  Get_User('H', 45)
where User.user_id = user_id_rech
```

The stored procedure is used like a table here.

I don't think that doctrine 2 allows to map a stored procedure, but I'd like that someone can confirm that to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(Writing this as an answer, because it's too long as a comment.)

Whether Doctrine allows this or not, I'd like to volunteer that your query will be inefficient (perhaps terribly so), because Postgres will have no means to estimate how many rows `Get_User()` will return.

Chances are that your function is a mere wrapper around `return query select ...` in `plpgsql`, or the SQL equivalent if the written in plain `sql`. If so, consider creating a view instead. This will allow Postgres to rewrite the query if needed, as well as use proper statistics on your table's contents, and probably allow you to get rid of the join altogether.

Better yet, issue the query directly. If you use it frequently, create a function that returns it ready for further filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Get_user is just a (very) simple exemple used only to make my question more understandable.

My real function is in fact a dynamic query builder which return data from several tables. Creating a view in this case is not possible.

Regards

Comment: note that you can tell PostgreSQL how many rows a query typically returns.  See the docs on `CREATE FUNCTION`